# How to save state in classes OOP?

Tags: typescript, oop

There is a  entry class:

```
class Component {
   public tools: Tools;
   constructor(private editorLayers: EditingLayers) {
     this.tools = this.editorLayers.getTools();
   }

   setLayerItem(layer) {
      this.editorLayers.setLayerItem(layer);
   }
}
```

Class `EditingLayers` is:

```
class EditingLayers {
    private editLayerItem: EditLayerItem;
   
    getTools() {
        return this.editLayerItem.tools;
    }
 
    setLayerItem(layer) {
        this.editLayerItem = new EditLayerItem();
    } 
}
```

I want to save a state of `this.editLayerItem` if it was created before and get access to all `EditLayerItem` in class Component.

Problem is that if there is no initialized `editLayerItem` object, it fails on the line:

```
this.tools = this.editorLayers.getTools();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `tsconfig` contains `strict: true` or `strictNullChecks: true` then you should get a TypeScript error:

> "Property 'editLayerItem' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."

I recommend turning strict mode on and handling things accordingly.  That means you either need to `throw new Error()` if something is not in a valid state or widen its return type to include `undefined`.

You probably need to be doing more setup in your constructors: either requiring properties as arguments or setting initial values.

---

> I want to save a state of `this.editLayerItem` if it was created before and get access to all `EditLayerItem` in class `Component`.

It sounds like you want to dynamically access the tools for the *current* `EditingLayers`, not the one that was passed to the constructor (if `this.editorLayers` is something that can change).  So instead of an instance property `this.tools` you should use either a method `getTools()` or a dynamic getter `get tools()`.  Both of those will be evaluated at the time when you access it so it guarantees a current value.

This code passes in strict mode, but it returns `Tools | undefined`.  If you want to ensure that you always have `Tools` then you need to ensure that you always have an `EditLayerItem`.

```
class Component {
    constructor(private editorLayers: EditingLayers) {
    }

    get tools() {
        return this.editorLayers.getTools();
    }

    setLayerItem() {
        this.editorLayers.setLayerItem();
    }
}

class EditingLayers {
    private editLayerItem?: EditLayerItem;

    getTools() {
        return this.editLayerItem?.tools;
    }

    setLayerItem() {
        this.editLayerItem = new EditLayerItem();
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqD28QwN4FgBQmC%20nOkhgFEATASwBcAZMATwFMAnASQvoFtp0NpfoAHAK4AjEGWDQKiZAC440iAG48PPsHgA7CBUaDgUxgAoAlF0x8LkgBZkIAOilIYAXmgb6Ad3lPlq3rgwA-HAoaABheHZ%20TXoNCjM-aHUtHT0DQ35GMgA3MDZoenIDGgZGCDlSSjINAHMSpghTbgsgxJr6eMdkEwTLPkYOwUYNa1s7Qsp4Rnqyu3aKBCcTXxaVCwgOmdYOHua%200fsJ4roGuw3qE5Y2dmXzPgDWglDKimq6y9Q73kycvPoCopba4AfgqgMu23Yvi%200Hmi26TRhFgGFCGIwoNkO4NKkOBDgUK3uaz45yBO0RiQsGLGRzJnFc7i8Lzpt0SDyAA)